# Where are the groovy properties for jdk extensions documented?

Tags: groovy, code-documentation

The Groovy JDK docs, here  http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/  don't seem to show the properties on the objects.  I'm familiar with this site: http://groovy.codehaus.org/ which has some examples allowing folks to divine properties, but it at least doesn't appear comprehensive.

Is there another place to find the JDK extension classes that includes their properties?

Comment: Are you referring to http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you were referring to this [API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/). Groovy 2.3.0 API comes with a [new look and feel](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.0/html/groovy-jdk/)

Comment: Yeah, for the Groovy JDK objects they aren't including the properties which are much more important in groovy since many methods are replaced by useful public properties.  The codehaus site shows some, but it's not clear that it's exhaustive.